# How do I solve such type of questions when time limit is about 2–3 minutes?

Tags: logarithms

If $f(x)= \ln\left ( \frac{1+x}{1-x} \right )$ then

$A.\,f(x_1)\cdot f(x_2)= f(x_1+x_2)\\
B.\,f(x+2)-2f(x+1)+f(x)=0\\
C.\,f(x)+f(x+1)=f(x^2+x)\\
D.\,f(x_1)+f(x_2)=f\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{1+x_1 x_2}\right)  $

As you can see, there four options and in the exam we get only 2–3 minutes to solve and I can't keep checking each and every option. Is there any other option?

Comment: In questions like this I find it easier and faster to give $x_1,x_2$ values and checking the results

Comment: If $x=0$ then B and C are out. Two options left. Took me 20 seconds. Can you do the rest?

Comment: $x_1=0$ sees $A$ off.

Comment: +1) This is actually a very nice problem. I got to take a pic of this for reference!

Comment: If you were very good you might notice that $D$ has some resemblance to the $\tan A+ B$ rule, and then you might look to see that $f(x) = 2\tanh^{-1} (x)$

Comment: Can anyone give me step by step solution for the substitution method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your constraints, $-1<x<1$

Set $x_1=x_2=0$ and try them.

Then:
$$f(x)=\ln(\frac 11)=0$$
$f(x+1)$ is undefined.

$f(x+2)$ is also undefined.

This eliminates $B$ and $C$.

Now to check $A$ and $D$.

$A$ works, and so does $D$

Now let $x_1=\frac 12, x_2=0$

We have that $f(x_1)=\ln 3, f(x_2)=0, f(x_1+x_2)=\ln3$, and so $A$ is false, leaving only $D$

Comment: mistake made allow me to edit

Comment: Answer is D. D is the answer given in the book

Comment: Why didn't you take x_{1}=1 , it's easier to solve? @Rhys Hughes

Comment: @TheReBel, $\frac{1+(1)}{1-(1)}=\frac 20$ which is undefined

Comment: But , in the 2nd option when you put x=0 then f(x+1) becomes f(1), then it's also undefined so doesn't that mean that we can't keep x=0. Sorry for so much reasoning, but you know, I can't help.

Comment: There are values of $x$ for which $f(x)$ is defined but $f(x+1)$ is not. Hence equations which use $f(x+1)$ are *invalid*